# ES6 declaring variables before or in loop

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Where and how should I declare new variables used in loops?

A:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(columns));
let cols;
for (let [key, value] of map)
{
    cols = value.split('|');
    //...
}
```

B:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(columns));
for (let [key, value] of map)
{
    let cols = value.split('|');
    //...
}
```

C:

```
const map = new Map(Object.entries(columns));
var cols;
for (let [key, value] of map)
{
    cols = value.split('|');
    //...
}
```

Probably A or B since everyone says let is the new var, but is there any difference between A and B?

**Edited:**
The variable cols will be used only inside for. I was wondering if there are some issues if variable is initialized inside loop (for example 100 times). So I wondered if it should be initialized outside loop. (A or B example)

`The purpose is not to get access outside loop, but prevent (for example) 100 initialization variable cols inside loop (because let is used inside loop - case B).`

Comment: You should always use the narrowest possible scope this is, example B.

Comment: "*everyone says let is the new var*" - beat everyone with a stick who says that without qualification.

Comment: "*prevent 100 initialization variable cols inside loop*" - that is the compiler's job. You don't need and should not do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In code snippet A, `cols` is accessible outside of the `for` too. As `let` variables are block-scoped, when used `let` to define variable inside `for`, the scope of the variable is for that block only. So, in B, the variable `cols` will not be accessible outside of the `for`.

C, is similar to A if `cols` is defined only once. If `col` is defined twice in the same scope using `let` will result in error.

Which one to use depends on the use-case.

1. If `cols` is needed inside `for` only, then use `let cols = ...`
2. If `cols` is needed outside of `for` too, use `let cols;` before `for` and then it can be used after `for` too in the same enclosing scope. Note that, in this case, `cols` will be the last value assigned in the loop.

Comment: In snippet B and C - when the variable is declared using let inside the loop - is the variable declared for each traversal of the loop or only once? This might be a performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between A and B is the scope of the var. In first case you can access `cols` also outside the loop, in the second you can't.

```js
let a;

for (let i =0; i < 2; i++) {
  let b = i;
  a = i;
}

console.log('a outside the loop:', a);
console.log('b outside the loop:', b);
console.log('i outside the loop:', i);  //If `var` was used instead of `let` then `i` would have had global scope
```